# Postgresql nest SELECT statement within a function call

Tags: sql, postgresql, tsvector

i currently setting up full text search in Postgresql database as described in this manual page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-tables.html

Currently i came out with this statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fts_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
  new.tsv :=
       to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.title,'')) ||
       to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', coalesce(new.description,'')) ||
       to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english',
        SELECT array_to_string(array_accum(name), ' ') FROM agencies where id = new.agency_id
       );
  return new;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER ftsupdate_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON camps FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fts_update()"
```

Here i need to add some fields from another table to index, but Postgresql not allowing me:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 9:         SELECT array_to_string(array_accum(name), ' ') FROM ...
```

Is there any good fix for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is wrap the select in brackets e.g.

```
 select to_tsvector('english',(select array_to_string(array['one','two','three'],' ')));
```